# Selecting the most recently dynamically created object with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, stopwatch

Below is some code that I'm using to create objects with Visual Basic:

```
    For indexCounter As Integer = 1 To TotalParticipants Step 1

        participantClock = New Label
        participantClock.Size = New Size(100, 20)
        participantClock.Name = "participantClock" & indexCounter
        participantClock.Location = New Point(139, (5 + ((indexCounter - 1) * 26)))
        participantClock.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        participantClock.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
        CenterPanel.Controls.Add(participantClock)

        participantStop = New Button
        participantStop.Size = New Size(58, 20)
        participantStop.Location = New Point(245, (5 + ((indexCounter - 1) * 26)))
        participantStop.BackColor = Color.Red
        participantStop.ForeColor = Color.White
        participantStop.Font = New Font(participantStop.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
        participantStop.Text = "Stop"
        CenterPanel.Controls.Add(participantStop)

        participantTimer = New Timer
        participantTimer.Start()
        participantTimer.Enabled = True
        participantTimer.Interval = 1

        participantStopwatch = New Stopwatch
        participantStopwatch.Start()
Next
```

I'm creating a label, a button, Timer, and Stopwatch. (Though I have sinking feeling I don't need BOTH a timer and stopwatch since I'm counting time.)

What I would like to do, is create the label and set that label's text to be the value from the stopwatch. The button that will be created will stop THAT stopwatch.

The problem that I'm having is that I cannot call the stopwatch by name since it wasn't created yet and VB throws a hissy fit at me for it. (After all it wasn't really declared.)

So the question becomes, how do you call the most recently dynamically created control and assign events using that control. If it's not possible to do, I do not mind dumping the form and starting over creating 30 stopwatches instead (but I'd like to avoid that, if possible).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What will the button do, besides stop the stopwatch?  Will it also stop the timer as well?

Comment: No. The dynamic button will only stop the stopwatch associated with it. A separate event will handle stopping the timer. I'm even trying to figure out if a separate timer for EACH of the stopwatches is necessary since it's only pulsing to update the label which shows the elapsed time and nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want the *timer* to update the *label* based on the value of the *stopwatch*. Is that right?

One thing that you might try that is a little hacky is this:
Define a storage class like so:

```
Public Class StopwatchStorage
    Public Property Stopwatch as Stopwatch
    Public Property Label as Label
    Public Property Timer as Timer
End Class
```

at the top of your form define a private list:

```
Private _storage as new List(Of StopwatchStorage)
```

at the end of your for loop do this

```
Dim storage As New StopwatchStorage()
storage.Label = participantClock
storage.Timer = participantTimer
storage.Stopwatch = participantStopwatch
_storage.Add(storage)
AddHandler participantTimer.Tick, AddressOf Timer_Tick
```

The above code would give you access to the three objects that you need in your tick function. You will have to loop through the _storage list to find the right "set" of objects but it should work:

```
Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, args As EventArgs)
    For Each storage As StopwatchStorage In _storage
        If storage.Timer Is sender Then
            storage.Label.Text = storage.Stopwatch.Elapsed
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I didn't try to compile that code so I'm sure there are a few typos but I think that should give you an idea of how to refer to the object without needing to use the object's name.

Comment: Running into a small problem with your code. `'Tag' is not a member of 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch'.`

Comment: Oh yeah, the Stopwatch object doesn't derive from the Control base.  My mistake.  I modified the post.  Try something like it mentions now.

Comment: Okay EverPresent. That change DEFINITELY works. I just need to know how to wire the button to stop that particular timer now. And to send a command to stop ALL the timers.

Comment: Great! Glad it's working. Try adding the Button object into the StopwatchStorage class just like the other three objects are. Make a Button_Click event and wire it up (just like the Timer_Tick is only "AddHandler participantStop.Click, AddressOf Button_Click"). Then inside the Button_Click do the same For Each that we have inside the Timer_Tick to find the right set of objects.  To send a command to all timers just do a ForEach through the entire _storage list and stop/start the timer or whatever. Let me know if you need more help on this piece.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to cycle through each one to get the results of each? That is, get the value of each Textbox and the Label?

Comment: Textbox? Did you mean Stopwatch? You could do something like: `For Each storage As StopwatchStorage In _storage` next line `MessageBox.Show(storage.Label.Text & " - " & storage.Stopwatch.Elapsed`.  Is that what you're wanting to do?  (Sorry these comment sections aren't great for multi-line code examples).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7326/discussion-between-paul-williams-and-everpresent)

Comment: There was two additional pieces I didn't include on the psuedo code that I guess I would have to add in. There's a label which will count off which number the participant is, and a textbox which will hold their name. I was planning on adding those to the storage as well.